# Force datetime to be UTC in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

By default MySQL will convert a [s]timestamp[/s] datetime that you input from your server's time zone to UTC automatically. However, my data is already in UTC despite my server being in EST. How do I force MySQL not to convert the inputted values from one time zone to another? Thanks.

Comment: You'll be in much better shape if both your server and your DB are set to UTC, and you handle timezones on the application level.

Comment: Avoid using `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL. This data type will run out of values in 2038.

Comment: I can switch to using DATETIME instead. That is not a problem. I have no control over the hosted web server, however, so I can't set its time zone.